# Parsing error in Java during conversion

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I was trying to convert a .txt file into .xml, and I was facing the following problems.
. How do I split the characters from 
    `<BookSet>
     <Authorname>10_1 J Martin; James L Crowley</Authorname>`
in terms of ; and the space after the number.

this is my code so far.

```
public class CONVTOXML2 {

    BufferedReader in;
    StreamResult out;
    TransformerHandler th;
    AttributesImpl atts;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new CONVTOXML2().doit();
    }

    public void doit() {
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:/Java Codes/JMartin.txt"));
            out = new StreamResult("E:/Java Codes/JMartin69.xml");
            initXML();
            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                  process(str);
            }
            in.close();
            closeXML();
        } catch (IOException | ParserConfigurationException | TransformerConfigurationException | SAXException e) {
        }
    }

    public void initXML() throws ParserConfigurationException,
            TransformerConfigurationException, SAXException {
        SAXTransformerFactory tf = (SAXTransformerFactory) SAXTransformerFactory
                .newInstance();

        th = tf.newTransformerHandler();
        Transformer serializer = th.getTransformer();
        serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");
        serializer.setOutputProperty(
                "{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
        serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        th.setResult(out);
        th.startDocument();
        atts = new AttributesImpl();
        th.startElement("", "", "Author", atts);
    }

    public void process(String s) throws SAXException {
        String[] elements = s.split("<>;");
        atts.clear();
        th.startElement("", "", "Data", atts);
        th.startElement("", "/t", "AuthorID", atts);
                th.startElement("/t","<", "AuthorName",atts);
                th.startElement("<",">", "Title", atts);
                th.startElement(">","", "Venue", atts);
        th.characters(elements[1].toCharArray(), 0, elements[0].length());
                th.endElement(">","", "Venue");
                th.endElement("/t","<", "AuthorName");
                th.endElement("<", ">","Title");
        th.endElement("", "/t", "AuthorID");
        th.endElement("", "", "Data");
    }

    public void closeXML() throws SAXException {
        th.endElement("", "", "Author");
        th.endDocument();
    }
}
```

please help. Also i need the solution by today itself. thanks in advance.

Comment: look at the split method of the String class

Comment: I did, that confused me even more!

Comment: Could you please add you txt file?

Comment: Sure.
"10_1 J Martin; James L Crowley"

This is how the txt file starts.

Comment: Please, at least one complte example, so i can run your code as is..

Comment: "10_1 J Martin; James L Crowley<>An Appearance-Based Approach to Gesture-Recognition <>ICIAP"

This is the entire first line of the text file.

Comment: The same format follows for 500 times.

Comment: @souvik445 saying "that confused me" isn't really helping us understand you. what did you try, and what is it that confused you? If I understand you correctly, you want to split "10_1 J Martin; James L Crowley" into "10_1 J Martin" and "James L Crowley", right?

Comment: @Stultuske No sir, I want to split the text into "10_1" "J Martin" and "James L Cowley" individually.

Comment: What output do you expect for this input "10_1 J Martin; James L Crowley"?

Comment: so, the result should be: substring_until_first_space and then a split call with "; " as separator?

Comment: And sir, by confused, I meant I am supposed to extract the string and then split it, so where should I put the extract function and where do I store the split texted. @Stultuske

Comment: yes sir. @Stultuske

Comment: It's written above sir, please check @NikhilMisal

Comment: @souvik445 In my last comment I explained exactly what you have to do. what more do you need to try?

Comment: @Stultuske Can you implicate the application via code? That would be immense help!

Comment: yes I can. No, I won't. these are very basic Java String operations.
1. to get the first part, use a substring call, and use as end-index the result of an indexOf(" ")
2. then get an array of Strings, by calling .split("; ") on the remainder of the (original) String.
This will get you exactly what you need. People will be a lot more willing to help you correct your attempts, compared to writing the code for you

Comment: let's not. I've told you exactly what to try. it is up to you to try it